# Upgrade ruby zsh (no rvm)

Tags: ruby, rvm, zsh

I am using zsh and ruby version 2.3.1.

I would like to upgrade it to 2.5.0. I tried to install rvm and ruby version 2.5.0; they were installed, but it also caused many problems because it wasn't able to find other gems.

I removed rvm, and it was back to the way it used to be.

I was wondering if there's a way to upgrade ruby withour rvm. I don't know how ruby was installed before.

When I type `which ruby`, I get `/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Comment: Please add the output of command `which ruby`.

Comment: Do you have homebrew installed? If so, do you have `rbenv` & `ruby-build` installed via homebrew? (you can check with `brew list` if they are listed you have them installed...)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using `rbenv` to manage ruby versions. You can type the following command to install ruby 2.5.0

`rbenv install 2.5.0`

After that, change your default ruby version to 2.5.0 by typing

`rbenv global 2.5.0`

For more information and commands, check out the [docs](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).